# Recognize Keyboard in Linux - Laptop Dell Vostro 1510

Tags: linux, laptop, keyboard

Linux (CentOS, Red Hat, Ubuntu) operating systems can't recognize my laptop keyboard, and I'm unable to work with it any more.

It had been fine but I don't know what's happened to it now. Note that it works correctly in Windows.

Any ideas what might be wrong and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

I pass this command to kernel when coming up:

```
linux i8042.reset
```

It's cause to run keyboard for a while. After each reset you should type it.

I also read somewhere else that by changing `/boot/grub/menu.lst` you can do it for all the time.

Find this line and add `ro i8042.reset` to it:

```
\# kopt=root=UUID=c10a4641-f9b2-8b06-7127-bb1ba1fe45d4 ro i8042.reset
```

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the laptop without the battery.

It appears that 1510 series had lot's of issues when the battery is bad.
Mine, sometimes, refuses to initialize the keyboard in opensuse. I have to hit ESC before X is started.

HTH

Comment: It not work again
I want to install CentOS
and ESC doesn't work.
after ENTER for install graphic mode
screen appear and ask to check disk ro skip
but keyboard doesn't work anymore